# How to compare reals and integers?

Tags: bash, comparison

I have tried all possible combinations that I could find to compare a real and an integer, but they all seemed to fail.

For example

```
if (( "10.0" == "10" )); then
    echo "Joy"
else
    echo "Damn it"
fi
```

I tried square brackets, I tried without quotes, I tried `-eq`, but that was for integers only. So not sure how I am supposed to make this work in bash.

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point comparisons.  [`bc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_chapter/bc_toc.html) is the standard unix system tool for doing arithmetic or comparisons using floating point numbers.

Comment: Or use a shell that does support floating-point, like ksh93.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bc`:

```
if [[ $(echo "10.0 == 10" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Joy"
else
    echo "Damn it"
fi
```

`awk` is also possible:

```
if awk -v op="10.0" 'BEGIN { exit !(op == 10) }'; then
```

Comment: `expr` didn't work though. I still got `Damn it`

Comment: Your version perhaps doesn't return a code. Try `if [[ $(expr 10.0 == 10) == 1 ]]; then`

Comment: Didn't work either, I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here either; `--version` is `expr (GNU coreutils) 8.23`

Comment: Mine is even older. 8.21

Comment: `if [ $(echo " 10.0 == 10" | bc) -eq 1 ]` bc seemed to work though. Edit: I was using `--versionexpr (GNU coreutils) 8.21` too

Comment: Nevermind. I think I might be wrong about how `expr` works. Just use `bc`. It actually becomes string comparison already, not comparison of floats.

Answer (score 1):

Convert both to float and make string comparison:

```
printf -v a "%f" 10.0
printf -v b "%f" 10
echo $a
echo $b
```

Output:

```
10.000000
10.000000
```